# How do you use parameter specifications for a class from another application?

Tags: applescript

I'm trying to use [parameter specifications](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/conceptual/ASLR_about_handlers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH206-SW12) for the `application process` class from System Events:

```
on someHandler(anInt as integer, anAppProcess as application process)
end someHandler
```

`anInt` works fine, but trying to add `anAppProcess` results in a Syntax Error ‘Expected “,” or “)” but found identifier.’ on the word `process`. I believe this is because `application process` is not in scope and is instead parsed as `application` as a single class and the token `process`, instead of the class `application process`.

I've also tried:

```
tell application "System Events"
  on someHandler(anAppProcess as application process)
--^^ Expected “end” or “end tell” but found “on”.
  end someHandler
end tell
```

```
on someHandler(anAppProcess as application "System Events"'s application process)
--                                         ^ Expected “,” or “)” but found “"”.
end someHandler
```

```
tell application "System Events" to set ap to application process

on someHandler(anAppProcess as ap)
--                             ^^ Expected class name but found identifier.
end someHandler
```

Is there a way to get `application process` in scope or otherwise use parameter specifications for classes from other applications?

This also shouldn't be related to `application process` containing a space; I have tried this for single-word classes from other applications as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A handler must be declared on the top level of the script.

But you can use an `using terms from` block which is not treated as a *level*

```
using terms from application "System Events"
    on someHandler(anAppProcess as application process)
        
    end someHandler
end using terms from
```

But I have no idea what you are going to coerce to `application process`

Comment: ‘But I have no idea what you are going to coerce to `application process`’  I eventually found out that `application process` isn't the type I want but instead what appears to be an internal class used by System Events. Thanks for the answer anyway — that `using terms from` is a neat trick I wasn't aware of.